# Shared library debug/Traps Modes while C/Cpp Development/Running

Tags: c++, debugging, shared-libraries

Say I have Application which uses two shared libraries libA.so and libB.so.

Application calls libA.so { User library } which call libB.so { Should only be called by libA.so}.  I make changes frequently to libA compared to Application or libB.so? Is there way I can trap all calls into libB with stack traces from libA and Application?

In short I want to trap all calls in chained shared libraries? 
Note that libB is not necessarily for system calls, so strace is not much of help.

Comment: There"s also ltrace.

Comment: @n.m. Is there anything that i could do while designing library, as part of practice or guideline?